# Installing Apache Solr on Digital Ocean Error

Tags: nginx, solr, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean

I've followed all the instructions at this Digital Ocean tutorial:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-solr-on-ubuntu-14-04

Everything seems to be going perfectly when I do the easy installation and the manual installation. But when I type in the URL containing my IP address and the port number, I get nothing. I've tried doing the same with my domain name instead of the numerical IP address. Still nothing. I'm not getting any errors during the installation itself.

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with Nginx which deviates a bit from the tutorial. I'm wondering if that's the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're not going to say how you've deviated from the recipe, it's really impossible to say if anything has gone wrong somewhere. Please use the most recent version of Solr as well and not the version used in the tutorial. Also, check if the server is available locally on the server with nc or wget.

Comment: Well I didn't deviate from the recipe very much. Everything executed without any mistakes while I was doing it from the command line. All their commands seemed to execute perfectly. I'm just using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and nothing more. I tried looking for more updated tutorials for Digital Ocean but this was the best I could find. All seemed to be going well until the time I had to type in the URL.

Comment: But are you able to connect to Solr from localhost (i.e. on your droplet)? What does Solr say when it's starting up? Does any logs show anything? How have you tried integrating nginx with Solr? Do you see any requests in your nginx logs? Does the error logs show something there? If you're connecting through nginx - does nginx actually respond? Does `bin/solr` locally connect fine to Solr? What port are you trying to connect over? Is the firewall open for that port? You're going to have to provide some context and how you've tried debugging it already.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I'm new to VPS hosting and using Digital Ocean. I have no idea how to do what you've said. But I'm going to do a thorough investigation before coming back with more questions.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is now. I tried installing the most recent 7.0.1 version. I followed this tutorial https://kreationnext.com/support/how-to-install-and-configure-solr-6-on-ubuntu-16-04/, I improvised by replacing 6 with 7 wherever needed: All was fine until the part where I had to create a "getting started" collection. I got a message that reads, "Failed to determine the port of a local solr instance, cannot create gettingstarted". So it looks like my installs are working but there's this port determination problem. How do I get around this?Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't count that as your install working, as that port should be determined automagically, and even if wasn't able to create the collection, the web interface should still be available. You can test if solr is actually running by doing `curl http://localhost:8983/solr/` on the server. Solr runs on port 8983 as its default.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'm getting a warning about low entropy and I'm also getting the message, "tail: cannot open 'var/solr/logs/solr.log' for reading. No such file or directory". When I try that curl http://localhost:8983/solr/ command, I get a message that reads, "Failed to connect to localhost port 8983:Connection refused". Alsot, I did some research and maybe the problem is that my server doesn't have enough RAM. I only have 512 MB of RAM with the cheapest plan, but I wouldn't mind upgrading for Solr to work. But first, I'd want to make sure that the RAM is actually an issue.

Comment: @MatsLindh, I found out what's wrong. All the ports except for 22, 80 and 443 are blocked because of the ufw firewall.

Answer (score 0):

I followed your comment and allow connection on port 8983

```
sudo ufw allow 8983
```

More details about [UFW firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)

Thanks!